# @media max-width doesn't work on mobile browsers?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

My `@media only screen and (max-width:860px;){` doesn't work on the browsers when I put the html-code inspector on mobile.

its mostly explained on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7PRM.png) image.

It does work on my other `@media` codes for example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .extramargin {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #click {
        margin-left: 40px;
        width: 90%;
    }
}
```

If more code is needed I can send more code. I don't know what part of my code cause I have 1200 lines of code and have to search a time before I will find everything to make a code snippet. But if its needed I can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell the browser that you want the width of device to be the ACTUAL width of the device. So, you have to set the viewport.
Just include this in the `<head>` section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Comment: wow, I thought I tried this before and then a lot of stuff in my website got placed strange. Maybe the first time I tried this I wrote the code wrong. But thank you it worked :D

Comment: Haha had the same issue a while ago. Drove me crazy until I realized :D

Comment: Thanks! A lot of users seem to forget to do that